# Phonegap Timing Issues

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, timing

I am having an issue with timing using phonegap with jQuery mobile and `setTimeout`. Everything works perfectly smoothly when run on my computer, but when I put it on my device to test it there appears to be a significant delay between when the timeout is supposed to be ending and the action which makes it

In it's most basic form the following timer should create the alert after 8 seconds as it does in a computer browser. I am finding however that it is taking 9.9 seconds on my galaxy s5, which for my application is a significant difference, especially when using larger values such as 60 seconds. Any idea of what is causing this or a potential solution?

```
timer = setTimeout(function () { 
   alert("time expired");
}, 8000);
```